# Every open map $ f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ implies

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> > Let $ f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be an open map. Then
> >
> > 1. $f$ is one-one
> > 2. $f$ is onto.
> > 3. $f$ is bounded
> > 4. $f$ has exactly two zeroes.

if $f(x) = x $ which is open. then $(3)$ and $(4)$ are not true

Please tell me about (1) and (2)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

$\arctan$ is open but not onto.

[The Conway base 13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) is open but not one-to-one.

If $f$ were also assumed continuous, it would have to be one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2-1}$ is a counterexample for $2$ (in fact it is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and $(-1,1)$ if we take the appropriate co-domain.